# How to switch to text console without logging out GUI on 18.10

Tags: 18.10, gnome-classic, virtual-console

Occasionally I need to drop into the text console (via ctrl+alt+f1), usually to kill something. When I try to return to the graphical console (via ctrl+alt+f7), I've been logged out of my GUI session and have to log in again and reopen all of my applications. Is there a way to keep the GUI session from closing when I jump to the text console? Previous versions of Ubuntu never logged me out like this when using the text console.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.10 with GNOME classic desktop.

Comment: ctrl-alt-t gets you a pseudo-terminal where you can kill things. Why do you need a PTY login?

Comment: The graphical console is no longer under f7, but under f1 these days.

Comment: @jdv Occasionally gnome-shell locks up and I don't have the ability to open a graphical terminal.

Comment: @Jos That's not true for me. F1-F6 each contains their own text consoles, with graphical under f7.

Comment: I would also like to know how to do this, Ubuntu 20.04